# PolymerJs Dom-repeat: observe array's sub property

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

I am using an array in a dom-repeat in polymerjs. Say, the array is items and each element of array is item. Then if there is a property item.errors for every item . I want to call a function every time any of the item.errors change. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Observer, e.g.

```
observers: [
    "errorObserver(items.errors)"
]
errorObserver: function(itemErrors) {}
```

Comment: But items doesn't have errors property. Items is an array of objects for which every object has a property named errors . so Items doesn't have errors but items[i] has errors

Comment: Can you try this, errorObserver(items.*). See https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
observers: [
    "errorObserver(items.*.errors)"
]
errorObserver: function(itemErrors) {}
```